# can not update document in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, save, mongoose, updates

I do not know why I get error when I do this way in mongoose with nodejs. Mongo does not save object seller.

```
exports.edit = function(req, res) {
    var id = req.param('sellerId');
    Seller.findById(id, function (err,seller) { 
        seller = _.extend(seller, req.body)
        seller.save()
    });
};
```

This is error:

> No listeners detected, throwing. Consider adding an error listener to
>   your connection. CastError. Cast to ObjectId fail for value...

When I change to do this. No error occur, but It is not save new value of seller

```
exports.edit = function(req, res) {
    var id = req.param('sellerId');
    Seller.findById(id, function (err,seller) { 
        seller = _.extend(seller, req.body)
        seller.save(function(err) {
            res.jsonp(seller);
        })
    });
};
```

And when I comment out

> //seller = _.extend(seller, req.body)

. No error occur in both way. Of course, I do not edit anything

```
exports.edit = function(req, res) {
    var id = req.param('sellerId');
    Seller.findById(id, function (err,seller) { 
        //seller = _.extend(seller, req.body)
        seller.save(function(err) {
            res.jsonp(seller);
        })
    });
};
```

This is seller schema:

```
var SellerSchema = new Schema({
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    },
    payment: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    },
    address: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    },
    shipping: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    },
    user: {
       type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    product: {
       type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Product'
    },
    price: {
       type: Number,
       default: 3000,
       min: 0
    },
});
```

This is req.body:

```
 req.body = {
            description: "xxxxxxxx",
            payment: "xxxxxxxxx",
            shipping: "xxxxxxx",
            price: "17",
            address: "xxxxxx"
    };
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add the Seller definition and the req.body content please ?

Comment: i made a test, this gist https://gist.github.com/anthonny/7786310 work for me.

Comment: Does it work if `price` is sent as a Number rather than a String?